# C# Properties in interfaces & abstract classes

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I was just coding a simple C# interface, and I put a property in it without thinking it through too far.  For example:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    object[][] Data { get; set; 
}
```

I realized that I'm a little confused with properties when applied to interfaces and abstract base classes.  In a normal class, this syntax would generate the accessor and mutator for a hidden string member that it generated behind the scenes.

**Interfaces shouldn't be able to have data members.  So, does this syntax do something different in that case?**

**What about for abstract classes? If I put this same syntax in the abstract base and the derived class, would both end up with a hidden member?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Interfaces shouldn't be able to have data members.

Those are properties, and those [are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx) [allowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64syzecx.aspx):

> An interface contains only the signatures of methods, properties, events or indexers.

See also [c# properties on Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513938/c-sharp-properties-on-interface).
As for your second question:

> If I put this same syntax in the abstract base and the derived class, would both end up with a hidden member?

Yes. You can prevent that by marking the property `virtual` on the base class and `override` on the derived class.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "Those are properties, and those are allowed", you mean that the declaration is allowed, right?  So this same syntax would declare properties in the interface, but not provide the backing data item.  The class that implements the interface implements the properties and provides the backing data item.  Please correct me if I'm still wrong :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Interfaces shouldn't be able to have data members. So, does this syntax do something different in that case?

*Technically* it's not a data member - it's a get/set method pair that has an *underlying* data member.  There's no implementation.

> What about for abstract classes? If I put this same syntax in the abstract base and the derived class, would both end up with a hidden member?

If the *class* is abstract and the property is `virtual` then yes, you will be overriding an auto-implemented property with another auto-implemented property (which is pointless).

If the class is abstract and the property is NOT `virtual` then you still have two implementations, but the base class is *hiding* the parent implementation rather than *overriding* it (which is still pointless if they're both auto-implemented).

If the *property* is abstract then the abstract class won't *have* an implementation.  You'll *have* to implement the get/set in your concrete class (which *could* be auto-implemented bot doesn't *have* to be).

Answer (score 2):

The property declaration in the interface is completely separate from the implementation. Thus you can implement it using automatic properties

```
    private class MyImpl : IMyInterface
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object[][] Data { get; set; }
    }
```

or declare your own backing field

```
    private class MyImplBacked : IMyInterface
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public object[][] Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Same scenario in abstract classes

```
    public abstract class MyAbstractClass
    {
        public abstract string Name { get; set; }
        public abstract object[][] Data { get; set; }
    }

    private class MyImpl : MyAbstractClass
    {
        public override string Name { get; set; }
        public override object[][] Data { get; set; }
    }

    private class MyImplBacked : MyAbstractClass
    {
        private string _name;

        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public override object[][] Data { get; set; }
    }
```